# awesome wm is unresponsive, htop shows it is in disk sleep

Tags: awesome-wm

I am running awesome for a couple of month now, so far without any issues, but lately awesome is starting to hang. That is, I can still use the last open program and other programs, like my music, keeps running but I cannot e.g. switch windows anymore.

When I switch into the tty, which still works, and I start `htop` I see that the awesome process has a `D` state which I guess means disk sleep.

I am not sure how to continue debugging this problem. Maybe it is something in my awesome config?

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 with Package: awesome Version: 4.3-4

Comment: It's probably your config, share it to be sure?

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52636847/1672598

For more information, read that link. The issue is that you should not use blocking functions in `rc.lua`. When you do, exactly this happens. You end up with a deadlocked process. The config is attempting to execute something, then that something calls something which calls something which wait in the window manager.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same symptoms with stock config, however the process state for awesome was T (stopped). While I believe this probably does not resolve OP's issue since D is clearly different, I've still decided to document this as an answer because it may still be more related to OP's issue than I think.

The issue was triggered in my case by certain but not all ALT GR + key combinations. One example was ALT GR + C. I launch my awesome with dbus-launcher and I saw that both awesome and dbus-launcher ended up stopped (T). It was possible to recover awesome with `kill -CONT awesome`, however dbus-launcher did not recover from stopped state.

The fundamental cause appeared to be a conda environment which was automatically enabled upon login. The conda environment had its own version of dbus-launcher, so when I ran startx after login, I ended up launching awesome with the conda dbus-launcher instead of system dbus-launcher. Ensuring that conda was not activated before running startx removed the issue.